# Tidyr Unite() Function Returns Empty Data Frame

Tags: r, tidyr, quanteda

When trying to merge two columns (pre and post) in a kwic dataframe created with the quanteda package, the resulting data frame contains only NA values. Using the paste() function from base R works perfectly fine, but I'd rather solve this issue with a tidy approach. Has anyone else experienced this before and knows what to do?

I'm including a reprex below, but unfortunately, in the reprex the unite function works perfectly fine. I'm wondering if it's related to the input being a data frame created with quanteda::kwic?

```
pre = c("Pre Text 1", "Pre Text 2", "Pre Text 3")
post = c("Post Text 1", "Post Text 2", "Post Text 3")

data <- data.frame(id=1:3, 
                   pre = pre, 
                   post = post)

data2 <- data %>%
  unite("merged", pre, post, sep = " ")
```

EDIT: I'm including a better example in the code below. "x" is a data frame that resulted from applying kwic() to my dataset, and speeches_meta is metadata associated with the texts contained in "x". My issue is that when running the unite function on the "dput" object, it somehow doubles the amount of variables and all of the observations except for two are empty (with the two that aren't containing a bunch of information from all variables).

```
merged_kwic <- left_join(x, speeches_meta, by = "docname")

dput <- dput(merged_kwic[1:3, c("pre", "post")])

dput <- dput %>%
  unite("merged", pre, post, sep = " ")
```

EDIT 2:

The following is the output I get after running the following code:

```
dput(merged_kwic[1:3, c("pre", "post")])
```

```
structure(list(docname = c("585662", "586622", "650973"), from = c(377L, 
1665L, 562L), to = c(377L, 1665L, 562L), pre = c("5 Dies kann weder durch", 
"tief in die Mottenkiste der", "unterstellen dass es ihnen um"
), keyword = c("Ostalgie", "Ostalgie", "Ostalgie"), post = c("noch durch Amnesie durch Gedächtnisverlust", 
"greifen würden 33 An dieser", "geht um eine Werbung für"), 
    pattern = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ostalgie", class = "factor"), 
    id = c(585662, 586622, 650973), session = c(241, 245, 56), 
    electoralTerm = c(13, 13, 15), firstName = c("Dietrich", 
    "werner", "Vera"), lastName = c("Austermann", "schulz", "Lengsfeld"
    ), politicianId = c(11000066, 11002108, 11002721), factionId = c(4, 
    3, 4), documentUrl = c("https://dip21.bundestag.de/dip21/btp/13/13241.pdf", 
    "https://dip21.bundestag.de/dip21/btp/13/13245.pdf", "https://dip21.bundestag.de/dip21/btp/15/15056.pdf"
    ), positionShort = c("Member of Parliament", "Member of Parliament", 
    "Member of Parliament"), positionLong = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), date = structure(c(10395, 
    10402, 12236), class = "Date")), ntoken = c(`585662` = 839L, 
`586622` = 1724L, `650973` = 647L), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("kwic", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: The main thing about a reproducible example is that it needs to reproduce the problem. Please test a sample of your real data to find a subset that reproducibe the problem and share it with `dput()`, something like `dput(my_kwic_data[1:5, c("pre", "post")])` for the first 5 rows of the "pre" and "post" columns.

Comment: Just edited the original post to include an example using dput() but I'm not sure if I did that correctly... Does it make any sense at all?

Comment: Run `dput(merged_kwic[1:3, c("pre", "post")])` in your console and copy/paste the result into the question. It will probably start with `structure(`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue here is that `unite()` functions don't necessarily work for `kwic` dataframes. After piping the dataframe into `as.tibble()` it ended up working just fine. Hopefully this will be helpful to people in the future!